# Why my regex does not return group(0) properly?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the dates from a large number of files. The date is on a single line, and is in the format of `"21 September 2010"`. There is only one such date in each file.

The following codes return the month only, for example, `"September"`. Why group(0) does not give me the whole thing like `"21 September 2010"`?
What is missing here?  Thank you!

```
months = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

pattern = r"^\d{2} +" + "|".join(months) + r" +\d{4}$"
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    fdate = match.group(0)
```

Comment: Try `pattern = r"^\d{{2}} +(?:{}) +\d{{4}}$".format("|".join(months))`. If it is on a line, and you read in the whole file, add `re.M`  flag.

Comment: You could make your regex much simpler by doing something like `r"\d{2} [JFMASOND][a-z]+ \d{4}"`. That way you don't have to deal with a join or the `|` operator.

Comment: @brittenb But that is quite fragile as it can match strings that are not dates (even though the risk might be small).

Comment: @JohanL that's true, and a problem that OP will have to determine is likely given their data set. That's just the first approach I'd try and if I saw any false positives in the results I'd *then* move on to the more rigorous regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print your regex, you will see it looks like `^\d{2} +January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December +\d{4}$`. When you apply it to `21 September 2010`, you will [see that it matches `September`](https://regex101.com/r/LoiDsZ/1) because the `^\d{2} +` can only be matched with `January` at the start of the string since the month alternatives are not grouped.

You need to *group* the month alternatives:

```
pattern = r"^\d{{2}} +(?:{}) +\d{{4}}$".format("|".join(months))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/04LxQE):

```
import re
text = "21 September 2010"
months = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
pattern = r"^\d{{2}} +(?:{}) +\d{{4}}$".format("|".join(months))
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    fdate = match.group(0)
    print(fdate) # => 21 September 2010
```